# Start a Docker container via SSH and kill it on exit (by trapping Ctrl-C)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, docker

I'd like to start a Docker container remotely via SSH and, once exiting the SSH command with `Ctrl-C`, stop the Docker container.

So far I have this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
docker run --rm alpine sh -c 'while true; do echo; sleep 1; done' &
pid=$!
echo "Ready!"
trap "kill $pid" INT HUP
wait $pid
```

I start it via, e.g., `ssh user@host 'cd /some/path && ./start_docker.sh'`

The problem is that when I kill the SSH session with `Ctrl-C`, the Docker container still runs, despite being run with `--rm`.

What do I need to modify so that killing the SSH session also removes the running Docker container? Note that I don't care about graceful shutdowns of the container itself—I just want the `docker` command stoppend and the container removed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `SIGINT` signal is not actually sent to the script when invoking SSH that way.

Instead, run `ssh` with the `-t` option:

```
ssh -t user@host 'cd /some/path && ./start_docker.sh'
```

More details are found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878/5893).